# Characteristic function is $2k-th$ differentiable, prove $E[X^{2k}]$ exists

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, characteristic-functions

Suppose there is a random variable $X$ whose characteristic function is $f(t) = E[e^{itX}]$. I tried this:
$$
f^{(2k)}(t) = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} i^{2k-1}E[e^{itX}X^{2k-1}\frac{e^{i\Delta tX}-1}{\Delta t}]
$$
I know that from Fatou's lemma:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} E|e^{itX}X^{2k-1}\frac{e^{i\Delta tX}-1}{\Delta t}|
&=\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} E|X^{2k-1}\frac{e^{i\frac{\Delta t}{2}X}-e^{-i\frac{\Delta t}{2}X}}{\Delta t}|\\
&=\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} E|X^{2k-1}\frac{2\sin(\frac{\Delta t}{2}X)}{\Delta t}|\\
&\geq E\liminf_{\Delta t \to 0}|X^{2k-1}\frac{2\sin(\frac{\Delta t}{2}X)}{\Delta t}|\\
&=E[X^{2k}]
\end{align*}
But I can only get $|f^{(2k)}(t)| \leq \liminf_{\Delta t \to 0} E|e^{itX}X^{2k-1}\frac{e^{i\Delta tX}-1}{\Delta t}|$, then I cannot proceed anymore.

My professor proved the case when $k=1$ and $t=0$:
\begin{align*}
-f''(0) &= -\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)-2f(0)+f(-h)}{h^2}\\
&= 2\lim_{h \to 0} E[\frac{1-\cos (hX)}{h^2}]\\
&\geq 2E[\liminf_{h\to 0} \frac{1-\cos (hX) }{h^2}]\\
&=E[X^2] 
\end{align*}
Thus $E[X^2]$ exists. Then by induction, I can prove the general case when $f^{(2k)}(0) $ exists, $E[X^{2k}]$ exists. But is there anyway to edit my computation in the beginning part to derive the answer? Thank you!